# solana pay examples required from customer POV

Tags: solana-pay

hi i would like to test solana pay from the customer POV.

Looked at Shopify and can't find anything, is there any other non-defi example handy?

Answer (score 1):

The Solana online store has Solana Pay via Shopify.

Check it out here: https://store.solana.com/

Comment: thank you this is helpful